# problem connecting to mysql - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, connection

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: `Warning`

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Filename: `mysqli/mysqli_driver.php`

Line Number: `203`

> `Backtrace:`
>
> `File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciblog\application\models\Post_model.php
>   Line: 4
>   Function: database`
>
> `File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciblog\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once`

Comment: Please add more information on what have you tried. Is the password correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the **database.php** file in

> application/config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root', // ADD USERNAME HERE
    'password' => '', // PASSWORD
    'database' => 'database_name', // DATABASE NAME
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

You can find more info [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)